# Magento 2: Custom field Dropdown options admin form always empty

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, select

I'm using magento 2.3.4 and I tried to create a custom form with dropdown options like this:

```
   <field name="year">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Year\Attribute\Source\Years</item>
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                         <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Year</item>
                         <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                         <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Year</item>
                         <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">year</item>
                         <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                         <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                         <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                 <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                         </item>
                 </item>
         </argument>
  </field>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Year/Attribute/Source/Years.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Year\Attribute\Source;

class Years implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

  public function toOptionArray() {
    $earliest_year = 2012;
    $options = array();
    foreach (range(date('Y'), $earliest_year) as $x) {
      $options[] = ['value' => $x, 'label' => $x];
    }
    return $options;
  }
}
```

but the dropdown options always empty, when i print the `$options` using `print_r($options);exit;` it shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2020
            [value] => 2020
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2019
            [value] => 2019
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2018
            [value] => 2018
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2017
            [value] => 2017
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2016
            [value] => 2016
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2015
            [value] => 2015
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2014
            [value] => 2014
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2013
            [value] => 2013
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2012
            [value] => 2012
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the option class with the below code. Please implement `\Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface` instead of `\Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface`

```
class Years implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $options = null;

    public function toOptionArray() {
        $earliest_year = 2012;
        if ($this->options === null) {
            foreach (range(date('Y'), $earliest_year) as $x) {
                $this->options[] = [
                    "label" => __($x),
                    "value" => $x
                ];
            }
        }
        return $this->options;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks it works, whats wrong with my code?